# How to attach a property in WPF/XAML with NULL as initial value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid and I want to show some details of the currently selected row in some textboxes above the datagrid. I am working with Telerik's grid and have SelectionUnit=Mixed and SelectionMode=Extended. Thus SelectedItem and SelectedItems are always null. 
My working solution is that I created an attached property which provides the values of that row if only cells from one row are selected and dummy values if cells from multiple values are selected.

that part of the grid is defined as:

```
<telerik:RadGridView b:myBehavior.CurrentRow="{Binding Path=Data.SelectedRow, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Name="myGridView" ...>
```

and the values are referenced in the textbox with this code:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(b:myBehavior.CurrentRow).TextValue, ElementName=myGridView}" />
```

As you can see I had to create a binding do a property in my viewModel. Is there a way to initalize the attached property without using the viewmodel? Either by providing a dummy record or NULL?

If I `set b:myBehavior.CurrentRow=""` I get an exception (invalid value). what do i need to do here to get it running?

Comment: not exactly answering here but in the past I have found telerik's own forums a fairly good place to ask specific telerik questions

Comment: I John, yeah I know but I thought this to be a question which is not very specific to telerik

Comment: do you need two-way binding in your situation?

Comment: no, oneway is fine

Comment: i would suggest trying to change the binding expression to one-way.  but sorry i don't have an answer

Comment: that doesn't help. thanks for looking into this!

Comment: I don't get the question. The default value of a reference-type attached property is `null`, unless you explicitly specify a different value.

Comment: @Clemens I added another paragraph at the end. hope that makes it clear. as to your comment for JohnB I think I had twoway in a previous edit that's why he suggested it.

Comment: How about `b:myBehavior.CurrentRow="{x:Null}"`? That would however have no effect if the default value is already null. What are you trying to achieve? Do you need the PropertyChangedCallback to be called?

Comment: Almost, but that just lead me to the right direction: I created an empty object of said type in the usercontrol.resources and assigned it the trigger the PropertyChangedCallback. thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Clemens for pointing me into the right direction. My solution to avoid an unnecessary roundtrip to the viewmodel was to create an object in the Usercontrols resources

```
<repositories:FahrzeugFlatRecord x:Key="myObj" />
```

and then bind it like so:

```
<telerik:RadGridView b:myBehavior.CurrentRow="{Binding Source={StaticResource myObj}}"...>
```

the TextBox remains unchanged. This solution was necessary as I have a PropertyChangedCallback in my behavior that registers an EventListener. If this was not the case, it would be sufficient to call to bind that behavior:

```
<telerik:RadGridView b:myBehavior.CurrentRow="{x:Null}"...>
```